# Dúvida para criar TableAdapter com comando SQL não suportado

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

Estou criando um relatório no ReportViewer porém o comando SQL que necessito utilizar para a Query não é suportada pelo TableAdapter Comando PIVOT.

Comando Utilizado

```
SELECT Descricao
     , Codigo
     , [012017] AS JANEIRO
     , [022017] AS FEVEREIRO
     , [032017] AS MARÇO
     , [042017] AS ABRIL
     , [052017] AS MAIO
     , [062017] AS JUNHO
     , [072017] AS JULHO
     , [082017] AS AGOSTO
     , [092017] AS SETEMBRO
     , [102017] AS OUTUBRO
     , [112017] AS NOVEMBRO
     , [122017] AS DEZEMBRO
FROM (SELECT C.Descricao, C.Codigo, C.Competencia, SUM(Valor) as Total
FROM Salario AS C WHERE SUBSTRING(C.Competencia,3,4) = '2017' 
AND Folha IN (SELECT idFolha FROM Folha WHERE mat = '****' and Servidor 
IN (SELECT idServidor FROM Servidor WHERE cpf = '*******'))
GROUP BY C.VDDescricao,C.CodigoVD, C.VD, C.Competencia) SQ
PIVOT (SUM(Total) FOR Competencia IN ([012017],[022017],[032017],[042017],[052017],[062017],[072017],[082017],[092017],[102017],[112017],[122017])) AS PT
 ORDER BY Codigo
```

Criei uma lista com o Retorno dessa Query, porém o ReportViewer não parece suportar a passagem de lista de objetos para projetos web.